# Disappointing Insert / Update Rates using Hibernate 2nd Level Cache and HSQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, ehcache

I need to be able be able to write to my database at a rate of upwards of 5,000 writes per second. At the moment, I am not able to manage more than 10% of that number.

I am using Spring to configure my data-source (HSQL) and Hibernate as my Jpa provider.

My entities are all flat (no complex object trees)  and I have employed Hibernate Second Level Caching (EhCache) with a Concurrency-strategy set to ConcurrencyStrategy.READ-WRITE.

Here is my Spring-Context for my data-source beans:

```
 <bean id="commandsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
p:entityManagerFactory-ref="commandEmf"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="commandsTransactionManager" />

<!-- Commmands Data Source Configuration -->
<bean id="commandsDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc-commands.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc-commands.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc-commands.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc-commands.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="-1"/>
</bean>

 <bean name="lazyConnectionDataSourceProxy" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="commandsDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Commands Container Managed JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="commandEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="commandsDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="commands"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                    p:showSql="false"  p:generateDdl="true" p:database="HSQL" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect">
            </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
     <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${jdbc-commands.ddlmode}" />
      <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
      <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
</util:map>
```

And here is an example of one of my entity classes. The 'AbstractAnnotatedAggregateRoot' is an Abstract Entity class from the [Axon Framework](http://www.axonframework.org/) which provides Aggregate and Repository implementation frameworks. Aggregates are essentially entities that must implement their own Jpa for persistence.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Cache(region="usersCache", usage= CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAnnotatedAggregateRoot {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6536766172448063298L;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private Integer subscription;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Calendar subscriptionDate;

    private Date lastAccessTime;

    public User(){}

    public User(StringAggregateIdentifier email){
        super(email);
        registerEvent(new UserCreatedEvent(email.asString()));
    }

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        registerEvent(new UserNameUpdatedEvent(this.username));
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        registerEvent(new UserPasswordUpdatedEvent(this.password));
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        registerEvent(new UserFirstNameUpdatedEvent(this.firstName));
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        registerEvent(new UserLastNameUpdatedEvent(this.lastName));
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return getIdentifier().asString();
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Calendar getSubscriptionDate() {
        return subscriptionDate;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionDate(Calendar subscriptionDate) {
        this.subscriptionDate = subscriptionDate;
        registerEvent(new UserSubscriptionDateUpdatedEvent(this.subscriptionDate));
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getLastAccessTime() {
        return lastAccessTime;
    }

    public void setLastAccessTime(Date lastAccessTime) {
        this.lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime;
        registerEvent(new UserLastAccessTimeUpdatedEvent(this.lastAccessTime));

    }

    public Integer getSubscription() {
        return subscription;
    }

    public void setSubscription(Integer subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        registerEvent(new UserSubscriptionUpdatedEvent(this.subscription));
    }

}
```

For completeness, here is the cache-region configuration in my EhCache.xml file:

```
  <cache name="usersCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
  maxElementsOnDisk="10000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false"
  diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" timeToIdleSeconds="300"
  timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
  statistics = "true">
  </cache>
```

Within the Axon framework, I dispatch Commands to try and change the state of the Aggregate. These Commands are within the bounds of a Transaction that is managed by Spring's PlatformTransactionManager.

Command Dispatch happens synchronously and I need to process 5,000 commands per second. Each command will fetch the aggregate from the cache, change a value on it and then persist the change before the next Command is dispatched. The problem is firmly at the time taken to fetch / update / insert rows, which I thought would be a whole lot quicker given the INSERT rates boasted by the likes of HYSQL and H2.

Any thoughts to ramp up speeds my an order of magnitude would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without the cache? Just to see if it's actually making a difference? I've had something similar, and the cache was actually in the way as it was being flushed all the time. I removed it and got much improved performance. This is not an answer, just a question :)

Comment: Interesting - removing the cache made absolutely no difference. I am still managing 500 writes a second with no cache.

Comment: That is interesting isn't it? Perhaps the question should also be why is cache not making a difference. That's unfortunately beyond my expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this entity is typical of your data (i.e. few columns without long strings), and if the database operation is an UPDATE, then the database performance should be comparable to what is described here, which does 5000 transactions per second (multiple updates, one select and one insert per transaction) with disk based tables.

http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlPerformanceTests.html

The database has 4000000 records in one table. With larger tables, the performance drops, especially if database size exceeds the preset limit for using Java nio memory mapped files.

You should also check the database schema in the .script file and see if unnecessary indexes are created, which can slow things down.

Comment: Wowsers - doesn't that say 55,000 TPS? If so, then i am actually running around 1% of available capacity. Something very wrong. For such simple objects, I might be able to pull out Hibernate and see if this has any influence. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It is 55000 TPS with all-in-memory, non-persistent tables, but 5000 with disk-based, CACHED tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're at the limit of what can be done with your database and JDBC and individual insert statements. Hibernate is not the problem neither the cache is. But your database probably can't process more inserts coming via JDBC.

But if you manage to use [bulk insert operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct), you can get a lot faster. With bulk I mean the style `insert into your_table select ... from ...`. Your reading data from a table, modify a bit and then you insert the result. There a bulk insert might be possible.

Comment: Really? 500 INSERTS / second is about the limit? The HSQL website boasts significantly more (I know it is dependent on object size / complexity / variable types) but I thought I could get anotherr order of magnitude out of it at least